# How to insert a hash in an ActiveRecord column on Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My Dev Env

**Rails 6.0.3.4**

**sqlite3**

**ruby 2.6.3**

and a **RoR n00B**

My Model `Goal` has a few attributes like `title` ,`created_on` etc.
Essentially standard types like `text,date,boolean` etc.

I have validations in place,I am able to read from DB, post from form etc.CRUD operations are fine.So far so good.

Now I want to add a new column called `tracking_data` which will be a type of hash like this

```
  {
    21-12-2020:true,
    22-12-2020:false,
    etc
    etc
  }
```

The idea is goal will have a column called `tracking_data` like above which is essentially a hash of `{ date:bool }`. It simply records if on a particular date(key), the user has worked on the goal.True or false(value). Essentially the user will select a date, check/uncheck the status for the date in the form.
I am using `sqlite3` currently. As mentioned here from the official docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html, I am trying to implement the same. What I have done so far, and **`which obviously is not correct`** is define something like

`store :tracking_data, accessors: [ :date, :status]`
on the `goal.rb` model file. By virtue of the `store` wrapper, I get access to the `date` and `status` accessor methods on goal. Which I use to read inputs from the form. The form code looks like this

```
  <%= form.date_field :date %>
  <%= form.check_box :status %>
```

So my query is

How can I read the date input by the user from the form along with the status and set that as key/value in the tracking_data hash.

Basically I should not be passing the `:date` attribute in the `store` function, because that has to be input by the user.

Additional
I am using the default Yaml serializer with `store`. Any help is appreciated and please let me know If I can clarify this further.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the column data type as `jsonb`, you can create or update records with something like

```
Goal.create!(tracking_data: { '21-12-2020': true })
```